# How do I tell what logfile JBOSS is using for my WAR file?

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j

I am using JBoss 7. 
I have deployed a WAR file in jboss/standalone/deployment. running using ./standalone.sh, which prints out a lot of logging information to the terminal window.

I am trying to adjust the logging properties, without success. I have tried editing the log4j.properties file in modules/com/company/warname directory, but it isn't having any effect.

I have tried modifying the logging.properties file in jboss/standalone/configuration by bumping up the logging levels to ERROR, but that also doesn't seem to be doing anything. (I'm restarting jboss each time). My log is still flooded with INFO and WARN level alerts.

At the very top of the terminal, right after the 'jboss bootstrap environment' prints, I do see the following line:

```
log4j: Default initialization of overridden by log4j.defaultInitOverrideproperty.
```

default initialization of... what?

Comment: try to configure jboss-deployment-structure.xml for logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points to clarify:

- the logging.properties in JBoss is there only till the logging subsystem (will provide more info later on that) is up and running, in which case the subsystem takes over
- the location you refer to for the log4j.properties seems strange, as you refer to ***module/...***, while this should mostly be a path reserved for modules, not your application itself (there could be something to do with standalone vs domain, as I'm more familiar with the latter, but it's doubtful.

So with the assumption that your app log4j configuration is not taken into account:

The logging management is done through the logging subsystem

Managing it for example through the CLI interface, and since you're focused on the terminal window output:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:read-resource(recursive=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "autoflush" => true,
        "enabled" => true,
        "encoding" => undefined,
        "filter" => undefined,
        "filter-spec" => undefined,
        "formatter" => "%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n",
        "level" => "INFO",
        "name" => "CONSOLE",
        "named-formatter" => "COLOR-PATTERN",
        "target" => "System.out"
    }
}
```

So if you update the level there:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level,value=WARN)
```

The level for the console will be set to WARNING.

Some more information for a more granular configuration now:

The logging mechanism in JBoss follows a "layered" approach, you define **loggers** (there is always a default ROOT logger) that define logging behavior per category.
The loggers are filtering the messages based on category and level, and sending them to the **handlers** based on their configuration, they can use the same handlers as the ones linked to the ROOT logger, or link to specific one(s) if preferred.
You typically have at least the CONSOLE handler and the FILE handler, but can add additional ones if you want

A list of loggers in the default standalone installation:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=logging:read-children-names(child-type=logger)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [
        "com.arjuna",
        "jacorb",
        "jacorb.config",
        "org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler",
        "org.jboss.as.config",
        "sun.rmi"
    ]
}
```

Taking for example *org.jboss.as.config*:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.as.config:read-resource()
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "category" => "org.jboss.as.config",
        "filter" => undefined,
        "filter-spec" => undefined,
        "handlers" => undefined,
        "level" => "DEBUG",
        "use-parent-handlers" => true
    }
}
```

This means that for org.jboss.as.config, the loglevel is set to DEBUG, and as use-parents-handlers means that handlers defined on the parent of this logger will be used for this logger too.

So for this category, all messages of level DEBUG and above are sent to the handlers, that will apply their filter to decide whether to output the message or not.
In our case we have set the CONSOLE handler level to WARN so all messages below WARN will be filtered out.

Hope this answers your question, or at least provides you with some points to consider while trying to resolve your issue.